# Why have I a NameError when I transform a local variable in global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I guess this question must have been asked a million times but I was able to browse through a lot of posts and nothing really solved my problem.
I'm trying to learn Tkinter and this little program is for let the user change the background of the program. And I try to put the foreground of a text label at the same color than the background.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

def chooseColor() :
    global colorCode
    global colorName

    colorCode = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Choose color")
    colorName = colorCode[1]
    window.configure(bg=colorName)

title = Label(window, text="Voyons ce que réserve Tkinter", font="none 25", fg=colorName)
title.pack()

but = Button(window, text="Please click :D", command=chooseColor)
but.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

But I always have the same error:

> title = Label(window, text="Voyons ce que réserve Tkinter", font="none
> 25", fg=colorName) NameError: name 'colorName' is not defined

But i did put the global variable before using them.. Can you help me? Thanks :D

Comment: `colorName` isn't set until `chooseColor` is run. That function isn't run until the button is pressed though, and that's after that `Label` has been created. For `fg=colorName`, what value do you want `colorName` to have before that function is run?

Comment: You never defined `colorCode` before the line `global colorCode`. The `global` keyword can only work on a variable that's already been defined in global scope prior to that line being run. So, to fix that you could put something like `colorCode = None` at the top of the file. However after you defined the function but before you call it, you have the code "`fg=colorName`", which doesn't make sense since you never defined `colorName` before that point.

Comment: If your title's color has to be picked by a user, how can they possibly pick the color before the title is displayed? In other words, the way you've set this up means that the title, with the user's color choice, has to be shown _before the user can pick a color for it_. Which is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know Tkinter is, but why don't you try declaring the variables in the outer scope, so it can be accessed. Try this!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")
colorCode = None
colorName = None

def chooseColor() :

    colorCode = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Choose color")
    colorName = colorCode[1]
    window.configure(bg=colorName)

title = Label(window, text="Voyons ce que réserve Tkinter", font="none 25", fg=colorName)
title.pack()

but = Button(window, text="Please click :D", command=chooseColor)
but.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's an issue here; the call to `Label` includes `fg=colorName`, which will be `None`, which probably will break things.

Comment: Hmm...you are right he must call the function chooseColor()  before creating Label object.

Comment: And there's no guarantee that defining `but` before `title` will fix anything, since the command function would get run when the button is clicked, not before. This is just an issue from a conceptual standpoint I think, since the title's color relies on a color picked by user input, except it's inputted by the user _after_ the program starts, meaning the title and its color are already being displayed. It's just an infinite chain of dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the variable `colorName` has not been initialized since the function chooseColor is not called untill the button is pressed. So what essentially happens is the following:

Python tries to render the window and can't find the variable `colorName` since as far as the interpreter knows it is non-existant.

The solution to your problem is to assign a default value to your variable.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

global colorCode
global colorName
colorName = "cyan"


def chooseColor():
    colorCode = colorchooser.askcolor(title="Choose color")
    colorName = colorCode[1]
    window.configure(bg=colorName)


title = Label(window, text="Voyons ce que réserve Tkinter", font="none 25", 
              fg=colorName)
title.pack()

but = Button(window, text="Please click :D", command=chooseColor)
but.pack()

window.mainloop()
```